# Google Calendar Sample app not showing events

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I have installed the sample Calendar project from [here](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-android-sample/instructions.html).

When I run this app on the emulator, I see three feeds:

1. Contact's Birthdays and events
2. US Holidays, and
3. my gmail account

I added some dummy events to my calendar by logging into my account. But I am not able to see these events from the app.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample project does not (I believe) include sample code to get events.

You will have to enhance the sample project with some of your own code.

When writing your code, can I suggest you look at the snippet at the bottom of the following page:

[Google Calendar API V3 Events List](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)

I used that and it is working very well for me.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks @Peter. But I switched to the content provider method to interact with the Google calendar. Though it is a deprecated method, but it is more easier to use. I found the code [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-provider-tests/source/browse/trunk/src/com/androidbook/androidcalendar/CalendarActivity.java?r=2&spec=svn2). However I am facing some issues with this too. Posted another thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166621/android-app-using-google-calendar-sync-issue)