# Android app using Google calendar - Sync issue

Tags: android, synchronization, android-calendar

I am trying to create an android app that interfaces with the Google Calendar.
I have followed the tutorial using content providers from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-provider-tests/source/browse/trunk/src/com/androidbook/androidcalendar/CalendarActivity.java). Parts of this code are explained [here](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar-3850276.htm).

I am facing the below issues.

1. I created a new calendar *TestCalendar* from my online from my laptop, and marked it as *Selected*. When I query for my calendars from the app, I can see this new calendar, but it is shown as unselected (selected=0). Any suggestions on why this could be happening ?
2. From my app, I add an event to the calendar by
   `getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);`
   The event is reflected in the calendar on phone, but it is not reflected in the online version. To push this new event online, I have to manually Synchronize the calendar, or turn the *Auto Sync* on, which I believe is not the right way in which this should be done. Any suggestions/links which could help ?

Comment: I have found a similar post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834257), but it looks like the problem there was that the event was not being inserted to the right calendar. :|

Comment: Guys, some suggestions pls !!!

Comment: Do you have any solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

1) Can you dump your calendar and post the result?

Notice: 
Android < API Lvl 14 you must set selected = 1
Android > API Lvl 14 you must set visible = 1 (selected is not longer available)

Dump:

```
cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse(CALENDAR_URI),null, null, null,null);

while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
   for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    Log.e("XXX", cursor.getColumnName(i) + ": " + cursor.getString(i));
    }
}
```

CALENDAR_URI = content://com.android.calendar/calendars (since Froyo) or content://calendar/ (before Froyo)

2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/11652415/411951