# Create syncable android calendar programmatically

Tags: android, calendar

i developed an app-feature to create and sync a local phone calendar through an app. Now i have to sync this calendar online, best through the native phone account. 
I tried to extend the URI's content values parameter (see API LVL < 8 parameter list below) by the account name and type but running after that into calendar freezes.

```
_id
sync_account
_sync_account_type
_sync_id
_sync_version
_sync_time
_sync_local_id
_sync_dirty
_sync_mark
url
name
displayName
hidden
color
access_level
selected
sync_events
location
timezone
ownerAccount
```

Is there another way to create an online syncable google calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a new one programatically.
Instead parse all available ones with

```
Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars",null, null, null, null);
```

and fill in your events into a existing one. 
But ensure, that your event got the same

```
sync_account
```

and

```
_sync_account_type
```